# Is it possible to import imports of another template in Jinja?

Tags: jinja2

I would like to group my templates into categories and then just include 1 templates instead of multiple. In simple words when I import a template I would like its imports to be imported as well.

Lets imagine I have a template `a.jinja`:

```
{% import 'b.jinja' as b %}
{% import 'c.jinja' as c %}
```

And template `b.jinja` and `c.jinja` are similar containing simple macro:

```
{% macro macroB() -%}
macroB
{%- endmacro %}
```

I have also a template `test.jinja` importing above:

```
{% import 'a.jinja' as a %}
{{ a.b.macroB() }}   {# <- this does not work now #}
```

Is it possible to make this `{{ a.b.macroB() }}` work?

Comment: Have you tried having this master template with the includes and every other template extends from that one? All includes should be available in that case

Comment: I actually went into direction of dynamic includes, where you can import based on string. For example you write 2 implementations 'system/linux/some.jinja' and 'system/macos/some.jinja'. Based on platform string you include specific implementation. This solved all my inheritance problems.